# Trying to install discord

Tags: software-installation, discord

Trying to install discord but then this happens.

```
Creating config file /etc/gconf/2/path with new version
Setting up libdbusmenu-gtk4:amd64 (18.10.20180917~bzr492+repack1-3) ...
Setting up libayatana-appindicator1 (0.5.92-1) ...
Setting up libc++1-14:amd64 (1:14.0.6-12) ...
Setting up libc++1:amd64 (1:14.0-55.6) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.36-9+deb12u1) ...
Processing triggers for sgml-base (1.31) ...
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.70+nmu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-1) ...
Setting up libgconf-2-4:amd64 (3.2.6-8) ...
Setting up gconf-service (3.2.6-8) ...
Setting up discord (0.0.28) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.36-9+deb12u1) ...
N: Download is performed unsandboxed as root as file '/home/operations/discord.deb' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)
root@nothp:/home/operations#
```

Comment: Looks like successful installation to me? It's just a warning.

Comment: It's unclear what the issue is here. Please update your question with further information as to what the problem is.

Comment: The `N:` part is a notification that part of the process required root privileges because you were trying to install a .deb directly and the `_apt` user didn't have read rights to the file. It's not an indication that anything went wrong.

Comment: Hey thanks it was actually on here this whole time.  I did not realize.  What I do fail to understand is why it says I am not root when I am & something about N:

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which architecture you have, but on distros based on Debian you can make a **manual installation** like this:

1. Go to the discord webpage and download the .deb
2. On the path you downloaded it make: `sudo dpkg -i package_file.deb`

And that's it! Hope it serves

Answer (score 0):

It was actually installed successfully I just did not realize it. (I am root though so I still am wondering about the `N:` warning.)

---

<sup>Answer copied from the question:</sup>